# saving tkinter entry box text to a JSON format

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I am trying to store tkinter entrybox text into a JSON format:
The expected output is:

```
{"objects": [{"neptun_code": "BVQYMZ", "result": "89", "mark": "4"}, {"neptun_code": "NHFKYM", "result": "95", "mark": "5"}]}
```

My output looks like this:

```
[{':', 'neptun_code', 'AUU4NA'}, {'result', ':', '98'}, {':', '5', 'mark'}]
[{':', 'neptun_code', 'BVQYMZ'}, {'result', ':', '86'}, {':', '5', 'mark'}]
```

my code looks like this:

```
    def __sendData(self):
        self.list = []
        for i in range(len(self.entry)):
            self.list.append({self.entryNames[i],":",self.entry[i].get()})
            self.entry[i].delete(0, END)
        self.counter+=1
        self.entries.append(self.list)
```

My tkinter GUI:

[image]

Comment: You want a `dict` with a list of `dict`. Therefore you need a global: `{"objects": []}` object where you append `self.entries` which have to be `dict` instead of `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a `dict()` (eg `jsondict` ) of what you want to save and then use the json module like this:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(jsondict, fp,indent=4)
```